# Unable to release viewcontroller

Tags: release, viewcontroller, nszombie

I need some help with releasing a controller in xcode ..im not using ARC ..take a look at this simple code from my main delegate controller:

```
LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:login.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[login release];  // code runs if i comment out this line
```

If i comment out the last line the program runs.
The program crashes on the last line ...i put in a zombie and here is the result:
2012-08-17 09:43:02.193 dialer[238:707] *** -[LoginViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x186360

how can i trace this and why is this even happing since im allocating and releasing right away.  Does it have something to do with retain , etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login controller is added as a subview and then released, but the addSubview method doesn't retain the controller (only the controller.view), so it can't be used any further.

You have to release it or you will have a leak, the solution is creating a property/ivar in your class and assigning the view controller to it (instead of a local variable), then release it in dealloc.

I think the point you are missing is that the [login release] statement effectively reduces the retain count of your loginViewController to zero, and the object is lost/cleaned up, which is not what you want because you still need it as long as your subview is displayed.

So your parent object (main controller, if I understand your example correctly) creates the loginController, adds the loginView as a subview (this is retained by doing the addSubview call), and then releases the controller, but you still need it to handle the login view! So the solution is to keep a reference in the main controller in order to retain it as long as needed (until you remove the loginView, or the main controller gets deallocated)

Comment: Hi Jeroen, if this is the case, then how can i release the controller i allocated just two lines above ?  Are yo saying that the addSubview method releases this object for me ?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, but am i missing something here ?  Did i not allocate the viewcontroller ?  I am responsible for releasing it.  To me i dont care if the addSubView retains it or not because i have ownership of the memory allocation (dont i ?) so i should be the one to release it.   Anyway if i did create a property what parameters do i give the property should it be (nonatomic, retain)

Comment: Yes you should release it but not before you are finished with it :) You release it, but it's still needed to manage your subview, so you have to make sure a reference is kept somewhere. You should probably use (strong, nonatomic).

Comment: I added some more clarification to my answer.

Comment: i cant use (strong, nonatomic) because strong is for ARC ... can i use ("atomic",retain) instead.  quotes on atomic because its not really there but should be (retain) .... if i use retain and your method will i still only have to release it once in dealloc or will there be +2 allocations ?

Comment: My bad, just use retain instead!